# How to read a Choice Field from Sharepoint 2010 Client Object Model

Tags: object, model, sharepoint-2010

I'm using Sharepoint 2010 Object Model. I'm trying to retrive the content of a Custom List. Everything works fine except if when I try to retrieve a Choice Field.

When I try to retrieve the choice field, I got an PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException exception...

Here is the code I'm using:

```
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://mysite");
            clientContext.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo("aaa", bbb");
            clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
            
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("mylist");
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View/>";

            ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(listItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
            {

                listBoxControl1.Items.Add(listItem["Assigned_x0020_Company"]);

            }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

clientContext.Load(list.Fields, fields => fields.Include(field => field.Title));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var field in list.Fields)
{
    if (field.Title == "YourChoiceFieldName")
    {
        clientContext.Load(field);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        return ((FieldChoice) field).Choices;
    }
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly for me using `microsoft.sharepoint.client namespace`

Answer (score 0):

When you read a ChoiceField in code , It will return a string array of selected choices. For example if you entered in the choice box of the column when you create it : "Company 1" ,"Company 2","Company 3 " , if user select option 1 & 2 , then returned array in code will contain  "Company 1" and "Company 2" .You must change the code to the below :

```
         foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
        {
            string[] values = (string[])listItem["Assigned_x0020_Company"];
            foreach(string s in values)
            {
               listBoxControl1.Items.Add(s);
             }

        }
```